# Purpose of a SSL/TLS certificate

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have been reading about ssl/tls and certificates recently to enable https for one of our websites.

As far as my current understanding goes, a ssl/tls certificate verifies that we as client are connected to the correct site or not. For that the signature inside of the certificate is used to verify whether the certificate is legitimate or not. And finally to establish a secure connection algorithms like ECDHE (Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman) are used.

My question is if I want to connect to a website say, "www.mysite.com" and I key in "www.mysite.com" into my browser address bar, I am guaranteed that I will be connected to the correct website. So what is the purpose of having a SSL/TLS certificate installed on a web server when I know that I am keying in the proper address.

Am I missing something in my understanding of how https works?

Also ECDHE algorithm does not rely on any information like public key from the certificate to establish a secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I want to connect to a website say, "www.mysite.com" and I key in "www.mysite.com" into my browser address bar, I am guaranteed that I will be connected to the correct website.

You are not. With a variety of techniques like DNS spoofing, ARP spoofing, hijacked SoHo routers, ... it is possible that an attacker reroutes your traffic so that it ends up at a server controlled by the attacker and not the actual  server you want to. Validating that the certificate you've got from the server is the expected one protects against such attacks.

Comment: I see. Let us now think of a scenario where the attacker has indeed used DNS spoofing and diverted me to a different server. What if that server has https enabled and provides its own certificate. Will my browser be smart enough to warn me that you have been attacked?

Comment: @DurgaPrasadReddyVennapusa: *"Will my browser be smart enough to warn me that you have been attacked?"* - the browser will warn you that something is wrong with the certificate. The exact warning depends on the browser and on the properties of the attackers certificate.

Comment: "Validating that the certificate you've got from the server is the expected one protects against such attacks." No, not always./ A DNS spoofing could as well come with a valid certificate issued with dns-01 method. Hence you won't see the problem, except if you look at the certificate in some cases, if the website uses key pinning, if the owner uses DNSSEC and you validate responses, and uses CAA to prevent further certificates to be issued.

Comment: "Will my browser be smart enough to warn me that you have been attacked?" If the attacker also generated a valid certificate (if it controls the DNS in some way, it can) the browser will have nothing to complain to. If you have some extensions that monitor certificate changes it might see and alert you that the certificate changed but 1) only if we went to the same site before the attack and 2) certificate changes also happen under normal course of execution, like their expiration. So, in short, no, just TLS alone with its certificate is not enough to be 100% secured against all attacks.

Comment: Thank you Steffen and Patrick. The comments do provide me more insight into the subject. Also if the statement  _"just TLS alone with its certificate is not enough to be 100% secured against all attacks"_ is true, I do not see a real use case of using a certificate. A http connection with encryption between client and server might have been sufficient if the protocol supported.

Comment: @DurgaPrasadReddyVennapusa: "A http connection with encryption between client and server might have been sufficient if the protocol supported"* - HTTP with encryption is HTTPS. But encryption alone does not guarantee that the connection is between client and the INTENDED server. While certificates are not perfect (i.e. no 100%) even a 99% is much better than the 0% assurance you get with plain HTTP only.

Comment: Agreed Steffen.